# What is the chance of getting the same id by using CreateUUID()

Tags: coldfusion, uuid

I am using `CreateUUID()` to create unique ids for my records but I notice that every once in a while I am ending up with duplicates so I wanted to know what is the probability of such a thing happening and how to avoid it. At the moment I have 300K records on my database and that number will only continue to get bigger.

The UUID has this format `7C26B210-5056-AB52-B9E1B2137830AC36`

Comment: http://jochem.vandieten.net/2011/05/05/the-definitive-guide-to-coldfusion-uuids/

Comment: " I notice that every once in a while I am ending up with duplicates". You are mistaken. If the same UUID is cropping up, it's because you are reusing it unwittingly, not because `createUuid()` has generated duplicates. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Random_UUID_probability_of_duplicates. Numbers measured in only the 100s of thousands - as per your situation - are inconsequentially trivial by comparison. You will never see a duplicate.

Comment: @AdamCameron it was a mistake in a 'ghost' file that I just found where it was picking up old UUIDs based on some random criteria. But thanks anyway :)